# Predict radius of multiple circle in images with CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am trying to calculate the radius of circles in an image using a convolutional neural network.
I have only the image as input and the radius on the output side, so the mapping is [image]->[radius of circle].

Input dimensions and neural network architecture are as following:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Model
img_input = layers.Input(shape=(imgsize, imgsize, 1))

x = layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', strides =1, padding = 'same')(img_input)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', strides = 2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', strides = 2)(x)
x = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2)(x)

x = layers.Conv2D(circle_per_box, 1, activation='linear', strides = 2)(x)

output = layers.Flatten()(x)
model_CNN = Model(img_input, output)
model_CNN.summary()

model_CNN.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer= 'adam', metrics=['mse'])



X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(image, radii, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, Y_train.shape, Y_test.shape)

(8000, 12, 12, 1) (2000, 12, 12, 1) (8000, 1) (2000, 1)

Y_train
array([[1.01003947],
       [1.32057104],
       [0.34507285],
       ...,
       [1.53130402],
       [0.69527609],
       [1.85973669]])
```

If I calculate this for one circle per image, I get a solid result:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**With more circles (see image) per image, however, the same network collapses and I get the following result:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Shape of Y.train for 2 circles reads:

```
Y_train.shape
(10000, 2)

Y.train
array([[1.81214007, 0.68388911],
       [1.47920612, 1.04222943],
       [1.90827465, 1.43238623],
       ...,
       [1.40865229, 1.65726638],
       [0.52878558, 1.94234548],
       [1.57923437, 1.19544775]])
```

Why does the neural network behave this way?
If I try to calculate the radius of the two generated circles in the image separately as described above, I get good results again, but not if two circles are in the image at the same time.

Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: How is your model supposed to know which radius corresponds to which circle in a multi-circle image?

Comment: actually there is no labeling of the radii and thus the network does not really know which radius corresponds to which circle. how could I implement such a labeling? (since I have just these images)

Comment: I guess you should approach as a 2-stage problem: first detect the circles, then pair them with the respective radius. But this is not a programming discussion.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by programming discussion? @desertnaut

Comment: That is is not about *implementation*, but about other aspects (design, methodology etc), which are not on-topic for SO; please see the NOTE in the [`machine-learning` tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).